# Iteratively subset rows & columns to replace values from mapping table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I would like to replace values from a specific column in `df` that match the `from` variable in `mapping_df`. `variable` in `mapping_df` should match the column name in `df`

```
mapping_df <- read.table(text = "  variable from to 
                 b 1 X 
                 c 1 Y ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- read.table(text = "  a b c d
                 X 1 1 3 0 
                 Y 1 2 2 0 
                 Z 0 3 1 0 ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here is what I envision I want to do, using base subsetting

Manually (this works):

```
df[df$b == 1, 'b'] <- 'X'
```

Automated (results in error):

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mapping_df)){

    df[get(paste0('df$',mapping_df[i, 'variable'])) == mapping_df[i, 'from'], mapping_df[i, 'variable']] <- mapping_df[i, 'to']
}

## Error in get(paste0("df$", mapping_df[i, "variable"])) : 
##     object 'df$b' not found
```

When I remove "get", I get no error but the values are not replaced

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `get` and subset instead

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mapping_df)){
  df[df[, mapping_df[i, 'variable']] == mapping_df[i, 'from'], mapping_df[i, 'variable']] <- mapping_df[i, 'to']
}

> df
  a b c d
X 1 X 3 0
Y 1 2 2 0
Z 0 3 Y 0
```

Comment: I see thank you for the answer! I also figured it out by creating an index and subsetting the rows by the index. Will post my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

manotheshark's answer works for me!

I also figured out I could submit an index for the rows of the base subset which ended up working as well.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mapping_df)){

    index <- which(df[,mapping_df[i, 'variable']] == mapping_df[i, 'from'])
    df[index , mapping_df[i, 'variable']] <- mapping_df[i, 'to']
}
```